# How to read recursively an object which looks like that

Tags: javascript, object, underscore.js

I have the following object:

```
var xhr = JSON.parse('{"name1":{"errors":["This value should not be blank."]}, "children":{"name2":{"errors":["This value should not be blank."]},"message":[],"name3":{"errors":["This value should not be blank."]}, "children":{"name4":{"errors":["This value should not be blank."]} }}}');

console.log(xhr);
```

I need to read recursively the `xhr` object.
The object I posted is just an example, it means that the children could be more or less.
Anywas objectReader should be able to get the following output:

```
name1 ["This value should not be blank."] 
name2 ["This value should not be blank."] 
name3 ["This value should not be blank."] 
name4 ["This value should not be blank."]
```

I did try to write the following code which it works partially:

```
_.each(xhr, function (xhrObject, name) {
    if(xhrObject.errors) {
        console.log(name, xhrObject.errors);
    }
});
```

This is the  http://jsfiddle.net/UWEMT/ resource.
Any ideas by using underscore how to accomplish this task? thanks.
​

Comment: this `JSON` is pretty strange, check if you could improve the generator

Answer (score 1):

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/UWEMT/6/

```
prs(xhr);

function prs(x){
        _.each(x, function (xhrObject, name) {
            if(xhrObject.errors) {
                console.log(name, xhrObject.errors);
            }
            else prs(xhrObject);
        })
}
​
```

If the object has erros it's an end node, else it's a children containing more objects.

Answer (score 1):

It's some strange looking json you have there...

But you can make a recursive loop like this:

```
var xhr = JSON.parse('{"name1":{"errors":["This value should not be blank."]}, "children":{"name2":{"errors":["This value should not be blank."]},"message":[],"name3":{"errors":["This value should not be blank."]}, "children":{"name4":{"errors":["This value should not be blank."]} }}}');

function loop( json ) {
    _.each(json, function (value, key) {
        if(value.errors) {
            console.log(key, value.errors);
        }
        else {
             loop(value);     
        }
    });
}

loop(xhr);​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YE6Qn/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
var xhr = JSON.parse("…");

(function recurse(obj) {
    for (var name in obj) {
        if (name != "children")
            console.log(name, obj[name].errors);
    }
    if ("children" in obj)
        recurse(obj.children);
})(xhr);
```

This code reflects the strange structure of your JSON (e.g., your names cannot be "children")

Comment: Worth mentioning that IE up to and including 9 has [issues with named function expressions](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/#jscript-bugs), an alternative when using non-strict code is *arguments.callee*.

Answer (score 0):

Just user recursion, jsfidle - http://jsfiddle.net/UWEMT/7/

```
_.each(xhr, function read(item, name) {
    if(name == "children") {
        _.each(item, read);
    }

    if (item.errors) {
        console.log(name, item.errors)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A plain js solution:

```
function convertObj(obj) {     
  for (var p in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
      if (obj[p].errors) {
        console.log(p, obj[p].errors);
      } else {
        convertObj(obj[p]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why the `hasOwnProperty`? The input was parsed from JSON and is a plain object

Comment: I assume a general solution is required, so guard against cases where Object.prototype has enumerable properties (people do silly things). It can be omitted if the OP wants, I wouldn't.